# Parent to child traversal more than 1 level

Tags: trigger, soql

I have to traverse from Account->opportunity->opportunitylineitem->product.family. I think this can be achieved by map, but i have very less idea on map please help.
I am accessing this from the account trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the account trigger gather the AccountIDs in a SET

Then write the query for the opportunity and put it in a map with the account ID as the Key

```
Map<ID,Opportunity[]> oppsByAccount = New Map<ID,Opportunity[]>();

    for(Opportunity o : [Select AccountID, (Select Pricebookentry.product2.Family From Opportunity Line Item) From Opportunity Where AccountID IN :THESET]){

       Opportunity[] tmp = oppsByAccount.get(o.AccountID);
       if(tmp == null){
         oppsByAccount.put(o.AccountID,New Opportunity[]{o});
       }else{
           oppsByAccount.get(o.AccountID).add(o);
       }

    }
```